# trigger call out bubble after searching in ios 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a searchbar in my view which is to be used by users to enter a keyword and searching according to that. I am using uisearchbar delegate for this. Right now the map is coming in center for which the keyword is being searched for, but I also want to display the call out related to that. I have lat long and title, which i assume would be useful. 
Here is the code:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
     NSLog(@"text %@",searchBar.text);
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [res objectEnumerator];
    id obj;
    NSString *stringToSearchFor = [searchBar text];
    stringToSearchFor= [stringToSearchFor lowercaseString];
    NSString *searchInThisString = @"";
    while(obj = [enumerator nextObject]){
        searchInThisString = [obj title];
        searchInThisString = [searchInThisString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
        searchInThisString = [searchInThisString stringByAppendingString:[obj address]];
        searchInThisString = [searchInThisString lowercaseString];
        if([searchInThisString rangeOfString:stringToSearchFor].location == NSNotFound ){
            NSLog(@"not found ");
            continue;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"found");

            NSString *lat = [obj latitude];
            NSString *longi = [obj longitude];
            MKCoordinateRegion region = self.gpMapView.region;
            region.center.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
            region.center.longitude = [longi doubleValue];
            id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation = [self.gpMapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
            MKAnnotationView *mkv = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]init];
            [mkv setSelected:YES];
            [self.gpMapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
            [self.gpMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

            break;
        }
    }
```

How can i trigger callout bubble any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've solved this but just in case ... according to Apple docs, SelectAnnotation only works if the pin is ALREADY visible onscreen.

> MKMapView Class Reference > SelectAnnotation
>   If the specified annotation is not onscreen, and therefore does not have an associated annotation view, this method has no effect.